# Do 2 java processes share JVM

Tags: java, linux, memory, jvm

Say I run 2 java processes in a machine, do they share JVM or they have their own separate JVM. I remember setting something like export JVM_OPTS="-Xms64m -Xmx1024m"

then which JVM is this for?

Comment: possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264309/simultaneously-run-java-programs-run-on-same-jvm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will start **two** JVM processes.

The settings in `JVM_OPTS` will be read from **both** when starting and both will create an allocation pool with a maximum size of 1GB

Answer (score 4):

They have their own separate JVM.
If you export JVM_OPTS, the variable affects all JVMs reading that value.
If you want to share JVM among different computations you must use multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

The two processes are separate, you can see two of them in the process list.
The options you specified will be used by all the JVMs you will start on that machine.