# Multiple Command Prompts / Consoles in Java?

Tags: java, console, console-application

Maybe an awkward question but I am wondering whether it is possible to have one Java console application running which is linked somehow to more than one command promt.

What I admire is to have a Java application which provides one console for reading console input, one for providing console output of type A, one for providing output of type B and so forth.

Any ideas or comments on that?

EDIT:

I am thinking on something similar to ..

`System1.out.println("output A");`
`System2.out.println("output B");`

**My particular problem is the following:**

I have to provide lots of output to the user via the console and in order to make it more readable and to provide a more structures overview I would like to use more consoles.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do it - but you'd need some way of sharing information (for example, a database, though that may be overkill depending on your usage) across both instances, and then push/poll for information updates.

Depending on your set up, you can have both be aware of one another, or you can have them be completely ignorant. You can also set up a third instance that acts as your relay - aware of all instances and handles messaging across all channels.

Comment: how can you do this? :)

Comment: Well, to really simplify it:

1) Create your store - say a simple data text file: data.txt
2) Have both loop and read the data.txt into memory
3) When the read data has updated, output to the console.
4) If you want one to ONLY read, and one to ONLY write, then you can  either set this up using command line arguments, or have them launch in a sequential order: The first one that opens is your reader. It writes to data.txt saying "Reader launched". The next one that opens checks to for "Reader launched." If it's there, it becomes the writer - otherwise, it's the Reader.

Comment: If you can't do IO, go the route of creating 3 processes - 1 would act as your "server" while the other 2 would be your "clients." Your server launches first and receives requests, and stores them in its app memory. Any client that connects is pushed the messages on the server. With timestamps, you can ensure they only get the latest messages. You can do this with Sockets (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html)

Comment: hm as I said .. It would be great if there is a way to simply have multiple consoles and to just direct output to one of these ... optimally without having some complicated client/server structure in the background ...

Comment: The link I supplied provides a pretty straight-forward way of setting up what you'd want. You can also try sharing memory using a 3rd party tool. Third option, is running two programs in the same JVM. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264309/simultaneously-run-java-programs-run-on-same-jvm - since two "programs" running in one JVM share memory, you could probably get away with doing this.

Comment: I think I prefer the solution regarding running two distinct programs because it will simply give me one console for each of them. I can realize these two programs by simply use two main-methods within the same project .... I will try this way, ... :) thank you for the hint :)

Comment: I'll also mention - I know with C#/.NET the problem is incredibly easy (I'm far better with C# than I am with Java) - but I would assume that if .NET can do it, Java can as well. If this was .NET, I'd have my console program (A) launch its own console program (B), and then redirect the output from B to A, and output.

Comment: that's a true story :-)

Comment: What operating system are you using? If it's Windows, you can use MSMQ   with Java using this: http://msmqjava.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily performed by logging outputs of type A and B to a file and using commands such as  tail/grep to see different outputs in separate console.

Comment: unfortunately since I am working on an embedded platform additional I/O is not an option for me .. any other idea (pls. see also my edit above)?

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to use *System1.out.println("...");* like you've indicated; however, System has a "setOut(PrintStream out)" method that you could use:

```
try {
    PrintStream psA = new PrintStream("My_Output_A.log");
    PrintStream psB = new PrintStream("My_Output_B.log");

    System.setOut(psA);
    System.out.println("Message for A");

    System.setOut(psB);
    System.out.println("Message for B");

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The above code prints the messages to 2 separate files.
I think this is what you desired for your application.

Comment: Hi there Marc.<br>No just one console can run one Java application. It is possible to write to either out or err. However, you can still use my suggestion. Why not create a separate class that implements the code I show. For example a function like "printFile.output(0)", where the int '0' specifies the file to print to. Then in your code call "printFile.output(2)" to print to the second file and so on.