# Can each main class can be thought of as a separate JVM

Tags: java, jvm

I have two main classes. I run them from different terminals in Linux. So are these two different JVMs ? And we will be required to use some inter JVM way to communicate between these two ?

Comment: Yes and yes. First search result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264309/simultaneously-run-java-programs-run-on-same-jvm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they run under distinct JVMs. If you need to communicate between them, look into:

- RMI: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html
- Sockets: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/
- Queues: http://www.rabbitmq.com/ (RabbitMQ is just one
  implementation)